# Use Mac OS X on VMWare that runs on Windows

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to have Mac OS X on Windows 7 using a virtual machine, preferably VMware?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but:

1. It is against the license unless you plan to run Mac OS X Server.
2. If you use the original VMWare installer from VMWare, it will be really slow, sluggish.
3. It is most certainly not legal if you use the images from "*the internet*". There are many prepared VMWare images, with VMWare cracks/hacks to get it working.

But, again. Against [the license](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf):

> … to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within 
>   virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already 
>   **running the Apple Software**.

… so, not from a Windows host, only OS X hosts.

Comment: Uuuhm... but if I remember correctly, VirtualBox can run MAC OS X out-of-the-box. But that's also illegal from Windows. You know, just saying.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes

Comment: It's not "illegal from Windows". It's illegal to run on a non "Apple-labeled" machine and he/she didn't specify what machine he's running on. What if Windows 7 is running on a Mac? :P http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm

Comment: Hmm you are right. Totally right. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: It's not allowed if you run Windows on a Mac. You **must be running Apple software**, citing from the license: *> run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within 
virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already 
running the Apple Software*. – I edited your answer, hope you don't mind. If breaking the license is illegal depends on where you live.

Comment: just out of curiosity why would anyone want to run OSX virtually under OSX? to try and fiddle with system settings without messing up the original system??

Comment: @posdef For example. I seriously messed up my system editing the system configuration to answer questions here on SU ;-) Another reason is to experiment with updates of vital software while your production system continues running, or running conflicting software packages.

Comment: @slhck "the Apple Software" is actually more restrictively defined and refers to OS X (Lion AFAICT). That means e.g. no Darwin host system.

Comment: @DanielBeck True that, it's Lion only in this case.

Comment: @slhck: source please about "you must be running Apple software on an Apple machine".

Comment: @m0skit0 It's right there in the license I quoted above. Apple software running on a Mac computer.

Comment: Right where? That doesn't tell anything about running non-Apple software on your Mac.

Comment: @m0skit0 Read again. You can run non-Apple software on your Mac, through Boot Camp. But you can't run Apple software (e.g. Lion) virtualized on non-Apple software (e.g. Windows).